# ServiceStack: Null Exception when using HttpResponse

Tags: servicestack

I have been loving the clean conventions in ServiceStack however I recently ran into a vexing problem. The user loads a "create" page to create an "ad", then posts the form data. The server in term should process the posted data and redirect the user upon success.

I run this with the debugger. The POST method completes without error, but the server always returns the error after the service is finished:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. AT
```

`CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.dfdcdedabeabca.Execute() at ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.TemplateService.ExecuteTemplate[T](T model, String name, String defaultTemplatePath, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ProcessRazorPage(IHttpRequest httpReq, ViewPageRef razorPage, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes) at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object dto) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;SerializeToStream&gt;b__0(IViewEngine x) at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response, IHttpResponse httpRes) at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response, Stream responseStream) at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResult.WriteTo(Stream responseStream) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToOutputStream(IHttpResponse response, Object result, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)`

Ive boiled the code down to this to isolate the issue:

```
    [Route("/ad/create", Verbs = "GET")]
public class AdCreateViewModelCriteria
{
}

[Route("/ad/create", Verbs = "POST")]
public class AdCreate
{
    //some things
}

public class AdCreateService:Service
{
//the error occurs AFTER this method is complete
    public object Post(AdCreate ac)
    {
        try
        {
            //do some stuff
            return new HttpResult()
                       {
                           StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect,
                           Headers ={{HttpHeaders.Location, "/home"}}
                       };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new HttpResult(e)
                       {
                           StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                       };
        }
    }


    [DefaultView("adcreate")]
    public object Get(AdCreateViewModelCriteria criteria)
    {
        return AdCreateViewModel.Load(criteria,Db);
    }
}
```